# Dataframe Difference

Tags: python, pandas

So I have this code below:

```
cols = ['Col001','Col002','Col003','Col004','Col005','Col006','Col007','Col008','Col009',]
import pandas as pd
dataA = [
    ['AB1', 'A',    100,    'NY',   0.01,   23, 'PQR',  1003,   0.002,],
    ['AB2', 'B',    201,    'NY',   0.03,   13, 'MNO',  1232,   0.004,],
    ['AB3', 'A',    234,    'NJ',   0.05,   54, 'ABC',  3443,   0.003,],
    ['AB4', 'V',    221,    'DE',   0.05,   67, 'ABC',  2345,   0.023,],
    ['AB5', 'B',    342,    'CT',   0.04,   89, 'MNO',  3457,   0.023,],
    ['AB6', 'N',    222,    'NY',   0.02,   67, 'PQR',  7665,   0.032,],
    ['AB7', 'F',    342,    'PA',   0.03,   56, 'ABC',  5767,   0.067,],
    ['AB8', 'C',    453,    'CA',   0.04,   34, 'PQR',  7563,   0.045,],
    ['AB9', 'B',    123,    'CT',   0.03,   65, 'PQR',  3465,   0.034,],
    ['AB10','C',    443,    'NJ',   0.03,   66, 'MNO',  3433,   0.087,],]
dataB = [
    ['AB1', 'A',    100,    'NY',   0.01,   23, 'PQR',  1003,   0.002,],
    ['AB2', 'B',    201,    'NY',   0.03,   13, 'MNO',  1232,   0.004,],
    ['AB3', 'A',    234,    'NJ',   0.05,   54, 'ABC',  3443,   0.003,],
    ['AB4', 'V',    221,    'DE',   0.08,   67, 'ABC',  2345,   0.023,],
    ['AB5', 'B',    342,    'NJ',   0.04,   89, 'MNO',  3457,   0.023,],
    ['AB6', 'N',    222,    'NY',   0.02,   67, 'PQR',  7665,   0.032,],
    ['AB7', 'F',    342,    'PA',   0.03,   56, 'MNO',  5767,   0.067,],
    ['AB8', 'C',    453,    'CA',   0.04,   34, 'PQR',  7563,   0.048,],
    ['AB9', 'B',    123,    'CT',   0.03,   65, 'PQR',  2353,   0.034,],
    ['AB10','C',    443,    'NJ',   0.03,   66, 'MNO',  3433,   0.087,],]

def getDataFrame(source,sourceName):
    df = pd.DataFrame(source,columns=cols)
    df['DataSource'] = sourceName
    return df

def compareDataFrames(sourceDataFrame,newDataFrame):
    targetDF = pd.concat([sourceDataFrame, newDataFrame])
    targetDF = targetDF.reset_index(drop=True)
    columnsGroup = list(targetDF.columns)
    columnsGroup.remove('DataSource')
    targetDF_GroupBy = targetDF.groupby(columnsGroup)
    idx = [x[0] for x in targetDF_GroupBy.groups.values() if len(x) == 1]
    targetDF = targetDF.reindex(idx)
    targetDF = targetDF.sort_values(by=['Col001'], ascending=[True])
    return targetDF

def getDiff():
    sourceData  = getDataFrame(dataA,'Legacy')
    newData     = getDataFrame(dataB,'New')
    comparedData = compareDataFrames(sourceData,newData)
    return comparedData
```

It works exactly as expected. The output is

```
print (getDiff()[cols])
   Col001 Col002  Col003 Col004  Col005  Col006 Col007  Col008  Col009
3     AB4      V     221     DE    0.05      67    ABC    2345   0.023
13    AB4      V     221     DE    0.08      67    ABC    2345   0.023
4     AB5      B     342     CT    0.04      89    MNO    3457   0.023
14    AB5      B     342     NJ    0.04      89    MNO    3457   0.023
16    AB7      F     342     PA    0.03      56    MNO    5767   0.067
6     AB7      F     342     PA    0.03      56    ABC    5767   0.067
7     AB8      C     453     CA    0.04      34    PQR    7563   0.045
17    AB8      C     453     CA    0.04      34    PQR    7563   0.048
8     AB9      B     123     CT    0.03      65    PQR    3465   0.034
18    AB9      B     123     CT    0.03      65    PQR    2353   0.034
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So far, so good. But I don't like the output. Even though it finds the diff, it displays all the columns for each diff row.

So, I wrote another method that would give me just the diff:

```
def createDiffDataFrame(diffDataframe,ignoreCols):
    diffData = []
    compareCols = diffDataframe.columns
    for eachContract in (diffDataframe.Col001.unique()):
        legacyRow = diffDataframe[(diffDataframe['DataSource']=='Legacy') & (diffDataframe['Col001']==eachContract)]
        newRow = diffDataframe[(diffDataframe['DataSource']=='New') & (diffDataframe['Col001']==eachContract)]
        if len(legacyRow) == 0:
            diffRow = [eachContract,'MISSING','MISSING','New']
        elif len(newRow) == 0:
            diffRow = [eachContract,'MISSING','Legacy','MISSING']
        else:
            for eachCol in compareCols:
                if eachCol not in ignoreCols and legacyRow.iloc[0][eachCol] != newRow.iloc[0][eachCol]:
                    diffRow = [eachContract,eachCol,legacyRow.iloc[0][eachCol],newRow.iloc[0][eachCol]]
                    diffData.append(diffRow)
    diffDF = pd.DataFrame(diffData,columns=['Col001','ColumnName','LegacyValue','NewValue'])
    diffDF = diffDF.set_index('Col001')
    return diffDF
```

Now, my output is perfect:

```
x = getDiff()
print (createDiffDataFrame(x,['DataSource']))
       ColumnName LegacyValue NewValue
Col001
AB4        Col005        0.05     0.08
AB5        Col004          CT       NJ
AB7        Col007         ABC      MNO
AB8        Col009       0.045    0.048
AB9        Col008        3465     2353
Press any key to continue . . .
```

My problem is:
Even though I get the expected output, in the real world with 114 columns and over 50K rows, it is taking forever to run createDiffDataFrame() module. Is there a better way of pulling off createDiffDataFrame? Should pandas even be used for this?

Comment: You can just simply using pandas to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try using `pandas` only

```
dataA['New']=dataA.apply(lambda x :','.join(x.astype(str)),axis=1)
dataB['New']=dataB.apply(lambda x :','.join(x.astype(str)),axis=1)
DF=pd.concat([dataA,dataB],axis=0)
DF['DIFF']=DF.groupby('New')['New'].transform('count')
DF=DF[DF.DIFF==1]
DF.sort_values('Col001')


Out[1927]: 
  Col001 Col002  Col003 Col004  Col005  Col006 Col007  Col008  Col009                                                New  DIFF
3    AB4      V     221     DE    0.05      67    ABC    2345   0.023  AB4,V,221,DE,0.05,67,ABC,2345,0.023,AB4,V,221,...     1
3    AB4      V     221     DE    0.08      67    ABC    2345   0.023  AB4,V,221,DE,0.08,67,ABC,2345,0.023,AB4,V,221,...     1
4    AB5      B     342     CT    0.04      89    MNO    3457   0.023  AB5,B,342,CT,0.04,89,MNO,3457,0.023,AB5,B,342,...     1
4    AB5      B     342     NJ    0.04      89    MNO    3457   0.023  AB5,B,342,NJ,0.04,89,MNO,3457,0.023,AB5,B,342,...     1
6    AB7      F     342     PA    0.03      56    ABC    5767   0.067  AB7,F,342,PA,0.03,56,ABC,5767,0.067,AB7,F,342,...     1
6    AB7      F     342     PA    0.03      56    MNO    5767   0.067  AB7,F,342,PA,0.03,56,MNO,5767,0.067,AB7,F,342,...     1
7    AB8      C     453     CA    0.04      34    PQR    7563   0.045  AB8,C,453,CA,0.04,34,PQR,7563,0.045,AB8,C,453,...     1
7    AB8      C     453     CA    0.04      34    PQR    7563   0.048  AB8,C,453,CA,0.04,34,PQR,7563,0.048,AB8,C,453,...     1
8    AB9      B     123     CT    0.03      65    PQR    3465   0.034  AB9,B,123,CT,0.03,65,PQR,3465,0.034,AB9,B,123,...     1
8    AB9      B     123     CT    0.03      65    PQR    2353   0.034  AB9,B,123,CT,0.03,65,PQR,2353,0.034,AB9,B,123,...     1
```

For you second out put( by using the previous result)

```
DF1=DF.groupby('Col001').agg(lambda x:sorted(set(x), key=list(x).index)).reset_index()
DF1=DF1.set_index('Col001')
DF2=DF1.ix[:,2:10].reset_index()
DF3=pd.melt(DF2,id_vars=['Col001'])
DF3['select']=DF3.value.apply(lambda x : len(x))
DF4=DF3.loc[(DF3['select']>1)]



pd.concat([DF4.reset_index(drop=True),pd.DataFrame(DF4.value.values.tolist())],axis=1).\
    rename(columns={0:'LegacyValue',1:'NewValue'}).drop(['value','select'],axis=1)
Out[1909]: 
  Col001 variable LegacyValue NewValue
0    AB5   Col004          CT       NJ
1    AB4   Col005        0.05     0.08
2    AB7   Col007         ABC      MNO
3    AB9   Col008        3465     2353
4    AB8   Col009       0.045    0.048
```

Updated Do not using `.ix` using`.loc`

```
DF1=DF1.set_index('Col001')
cols = ['Col001','Col002','Col003','Col004','Col005','Col006','Col007','Col008','Col009',]
DF2=DF1.loc[:,DF1.columns.isin(cols)].reset_index()
DF3=pd.melt(DF2,id_vars=['Col001'])
DF3['select']=DF3.value.apply(lambda x : len(x))
DF4=DF3.loc[(DF3['select']>1)]
pd.concat([DF4.reset_index(drop=True),pd.DataFrame(DF4.value.values.tolist())],axis=1).\
    rename(columns={0:'LegacyValue',1:'NewValue'}).drop(['value','select'],axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Let me evaluate its performance. Thanks again!

Comment: @PankajSingh glad it help ~ just a tips, if you are working at pandas , try to avoid for loop ~

Comment: Hey Wen, with your first piece, I am assuming with you are suggesting to replace  compareDataFrames? With that, I am getting the following error in 
 the line DF['DIFF']=DF.groupby('New').transform('count'). Error is error: Wrong number of items passed 10, placement implies 1

Comment: @PankajSingh change it to `DF.groupby('New')['New'].transform('count')`

Comment: Doing that gives me a different output that what you've pasted.Performance-wise, how bad to you think my compareDataFrames() is compared to your suggestion. I have used only pandas in that module

Comment: @PankajSingh the for loop in `compareDataFrames()` inefficient

Comment: @PankajSingh then what is the problem here ?~

Comment: It worked. Just needed to add this line at the end of your 1st part - DF = DF.drop(['New'], axis=1)

Comment: Could you explain me these two lines? DF2=DF1.ix[:,2:10].reset_index()
DF3=pd.melt(DF2,id_vars=['Col001']).. while the whole thing works, the end table in my real world does not tell me correctly which is dataA and which is dataB

Comment: @PankajSingh please check update , also, a tips, in the future , please provide a reproduced data sample

Comment: Noticing two issues Ken: (1) Column "NewValue' and 'LegacyValue' is flipping on certain cases and (2) Its dropping rows where dataA does not have in dataB (which I admit is my fault). My dataset should have had that examples. Your point on reproducable data, well taken. I just didn't want to put 114 columns X 50K rows in this question. I am working thru the first point. Second point is what I am having challenge with