# ValueError when trying to find the difference between two dataframes

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, diff

This is my code to compare difference between 2 xlsx files:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('SnapshotID_Old.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('SnapshotID_New.xlsx')

difference = df1[df1 != df2]
print difference
```

It gives me this error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

What's missing?

Comment: Hope the link will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45822572/dataframe-difference/45822762#45822762

Comment: It looks like your data frames have different headers.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ can you please elaborate?

Comment: I can elaborate if you paste some of your data here.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Both files contains 100(s) of entries. 
Any tips on how I can fix the issue instead?

Comment: Yes, I can write an answer but you're forcing me to take stabs in the dark. It'll be up to you to work my suggestions into your code yourself.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Not exactly. 
I appreciate your help and answer. Thank you. 
I'll have to dig in more into my code and read about the error that it;s throwing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably solved this already, but as [COLDSPEED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947593/valueerror-when-trying-to-find-the-difference-between-two-dataframes#comment78854395_45947593) said, you probably have different headers in your Excel.

You could try using `eq` or `ne` [flexible comparison methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#flexible-comparisons) instead:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('SnapshotID_Old.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('SnapshotID_New.xlsx')

difference = df1[df1.ne(df2)]
print difference
```